# Is the modulus of curvature the speed at which tangents change direction?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, trigonometry

I'm having trouble understanding an argument: the modulus of curvature it is the speed at which tangents change direction.

Let $\alpha:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a plane curve arc length parametrized and $k(s)$ the curvature of $\alpha$ is $s$. Consider the tangent vectors $\alpha'(s_0)$ and $\alpha'(s_0+h)$, where $s_0 \in I$ is fixed and $s_0 + h \in I$. Denote by $\phi(h)$ the angle between these two vectors, ie,
\begin{equation}
\cos\phi(h) = \langle  \alpha'(s_0) ,\alpha'(s_0+h) \rangle.
\end{equation}
(because $|\alpha'(s_0)| = |\alpha'(s_0+ h)| = 1$).

The limit $\displaystyle \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(h)}{h}$ is the speed at which tangents change direction. We have
\begin{equation}
 |\alpha'(s_0+h) - \alpha'(s_0)| = 2 \sin\frac{\phi(h)}{2}
\end{equation}
for all $h$ and so
\begin{equation}
|k(s_0)| = |\alpha''(s_0)| = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(h)}{h}.
\end{equation}

**Comments:**
I'm not able to verify the last two equations:

$$|\alpha'(s_0+h) - \alpha'(s_0)|^2 = |\alpha'(s_0+h)|^2 - 2 \langle \alpha'(s_0+h) , \alpha'(s_0) \rangle + |\alpha'(s_0)|^2 = 2 - 2\cos{\phi(h)}.$$

I don't know which trigonometric identity is being used.

The last equation is also not being able to verify.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation uses [cosine double-angle formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html):
$$
\cos\phi=1-2\sin^2{\phi\over2}.
$$
The second equation features a standard trick to compute the limit:
$$
|\alpha''(s_0)|
=\lim_{h\to0}{|\alpha'(s_0+h) - \alpha'(s_0)|\over h} 
= \lim_{h\to0}\left({2\over h} \sin\frac{\phi(h)}{2}\right)
\\
= \lim_{h\to0}\left({\phi(h)\over h}\cdot {\sin(\phi(h)/2)\over\phi(h)/2}\right)
= \lim_{h\to0}\left({\phi(h)\over h}\right),
$$
because $\displaystyle{\sin\theta\over\theta}\to1$ for $\theta\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$|\alpha'(s_0+h) - \alpha'(s_0)|^2 = \langle \alpha'(s_0+h) - \alpha'(s_0),\alpha'(s_0+h) - \alpha'(s_0)\rangle .$$
Now apply linearity and symmetry of scalar product (we have real vectors).
In other words: expand.

The vectors are unit, this gives the single $2$ in the final result, the cosine follows from your starting notation.

Comment: Thank you your help.

Comment: @Croos you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier, alternative solution. Without loss of generality, let's assume $\alpha'(s_0)=(1,0)$. Then, by definition, $\alpha'(s_0+h)=(\cos\phi(h),\sin\phi(h))$. Differentiating, we find by the chain rule that
$$|k(s_0+h)| = \|\alpha''(s_0+h)\| = |\phi'(h)|.$$
(By the way, you're missing an absolute value in your final equation for $|k'(s_0)|$. If the curve is concave at $s_0$, the derivative $\phi'(0)$ will be negative.)

Comment: I didn't understand why $\alpha'(s_0) = (\cos{\phi(h)}, \sin{\phi(h)})$.

Comment: I said that was $\alpha’(s_0+h)$. Note that we start with $\phi(s_0)=0$ and give the angle between the tangent vectors. Just think about coordinates on the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As an example let $\alpha(s_o)= \dfrac{s^3}{6 a^2}$ be position vector and let the curve with unit speed slope be

$$\alpha'(s_o)=\phi=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{s^2}{2a^2}$$

(for a Clothoid spiral) expressed in terms of arc distance $s$, and  evaluated at this point.

Differentiate with respect to $s$

$$\alpha''(s_o)= \dfrac{\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{(1+(\dfrac{dy}{dx})^2)^\frac32}=\kappa=\dfrac{d\phi}{ds}=\dfrac{s}{a^2}$$

which is its intrinsic/natural equation.

Comment: Thank you your help.